# Decode 'xorarlpziebpwanywxnf' to find the hidden message

Tags: cipher, number-sequence, sequence

Try to find the hidden message in the text: 
`xorarlpziebpwanywxnf`

These seemingly random numbers will help you solve the puzzle:
`-1 0 -3 1 -1 -3 4 4 4 1 2 3 -2 1 -2 4 -3 -2 2 1`

Hint:

> Each number affects the corresponding letter

Comment: Starting the text with xor is a good red herring

Comment: @RossMillikan  That was actually an accident, my generation script was completely random!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you

> convert each letter to its numerical value (A = 0, B = 1, ... Z = 25) and then subtract the corresponding value in the list of numbers. Then convert the result, mod 26, back into letters, e.g.
>
> x => 23
>  23 - (-1) = 24
>  24 => y
>
> The resulting message spells "youzsolvedzmyzpuzzle," so the solution is **YOU SOLVED MY PUZZLE**.

Comment: Are the "z"s meant to be spaces?

Comment: @Ross Presser Yes, the z's are meant to be spaces